# resource not found in collection @nestjs/schematics

Tags: node.js, angular, nestjs

[image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDMCk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxtwj.png)

hello I try to use https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/crud-generator but I don't know why that not working my CLI it's updated

Comment: Hi@Jonathan and welcome to our community! In order to find solution to your problem, you need to provide much more details in regards to what are you trying to achieve, what have you done so far and what have you tried and didn't work. Please include all relevant code, not images of it, so, if someone has time to test it, can easily copy/paste it. Always have in mind that someone will come to your question looking for solution to the same problem you have

Answer (score 1):

I was reading the previous answers, but I had to update both `@nestjs/cli` and `@nestjs/schematics` in order to be able to run `nest g resource mynewresource` .

Answer (score 0):

You must update the package `@nestjs/schematics` use `npm i @nestjs/schematics`

Answer (score 0):

you need to type nest g resource module-name. Remove the npx part